# Discord.py v3 (rewrite) Trying to match user input to a list of pre-set tuples

Tags: python, tuples, discord, discord.py

Working on a character sheet bot for discord for some RP servers I'm in. I'm in the process of adding an area for editing character info after its already been gathered. I have a list of tuples predefined for the initial loop of info gathering, but for the edit function, I'm trying to get the users input to match up with one of these predefined tuples. I don't know...where exactly I need to turn for this? Like, I can see the logic of what I'm trying to do, but my experience level in python is next to nil.

At this current point in time, I'm just running a series of if/then statements, but I'd like to get the code to loop iterate through the info gathering code I have until the user tells the bot that they're done editing, right now the bot has to be triggered each time they want to edit.

```
@commands.command()
async def edit(self, ctx):
def check(message):
    return message.author == ctx.message.author
member = ctx.author
n = await self.config.member(member).name()
await ctx.send("Accessing Character Data for {}. . .".format(n))
await asyncio.sleep(1)
await ctx.send("1: Name \n 2: Race \n 3: Gender \n 4: Age \n 5: World of Origin \n 6: Profession/Class/Occupation \n 7: Eyes \n 8: Hair \n 9: Height \n 10: Weight \n 11: Body Mods \n 12: Description \n 13: Primary Weapon \n 14: Secondary Weapon \n 15: Magic/Tech Skill 1 \n 16: Magic/Tech Skill 2 \n 17:Magic/Tech Skill 3 \n 18: Magic/Tech Skill 4 \n 19: Magic/Tech Skill 5 \n 20: Equipped Weapon(s) \n 21: Equipped Armor \n 22: Combat Role")
i = 0
while i == 0:
    await ctx.send("Which trait would you like to edit? Please only respond with the numerical value for the selected trait.")
    try:
        input = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return
    input = input.content
    ii = 0
    while ii == 0:
        if input == "1":
            info_type = ("name", "Name")
            await self.add_char_info(ctx, info_type, member)
            await ctx.send("Would you like to edit another trait?")
            try:
                msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
            except asynico.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("You took too long to respond. Terminating.")
                i = 1
                ii = 1
                return
            msg = msg.content.lower()
            if msg == "yes":
                ii = 0
            elif msg == "no":
                i = 1
                ii = 1
                await ctx.send("Closing Character Editor")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Please enter yes or no.")
```

`add_char_info(ctx, info_type, member)` refers to my info gathering loop, which I can post if necessary

As I have the code right now, its functioning properly, this is more just a cry for help to get it to do what I actually want it to do, which is convert a user response of `x` where `x` is a number 1-22 as per the menu given, then match that input value to the proper tuple in a predefined list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a `dictionary` to store your user responses of `x` as `keys` and storing your tuples as the `values` in which you would like to act upon once the user response matches the dictionary key.

[How to use dictionaries in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python) is a good starting point

Comment: so, funny enough, the Config variables are already stored as a library. which means, I think I know how to get this done the `dictionary` is titled `default_globals` which makes me think all I need to do is change that code around a bit so that it takes the numerical input as a key to the value inside that 'default_globals' dictionary

Comment: Though upon thinking more on this, and reading over that page your linked, I'm back to being stumped lol

Comment: Maybe its just because its what I have the firmest grasp on, but for how I want to do this, I feel like the endless chain of if/then's is the only route to go lmfao

Comment: @BaileySinger You can use tuples as the dictionary keys, and also if its needed you can also use dictionaries/tuples/lists as the dictionary values. To simply put it, if you have a logic tree, draw it out on paper and then think about how to translate it to a dictionary. It will be more organised that way and future additions to the code would just be dictionary changes. Hope this helps

Comment: Also, you can put functions as dictionary values too